# Android: Difference between UserManager's isUserUnlocked and KeyguardManager's isKeyguardLocked

Tags: android, multi-user, keyguard, usermanager, keyguardlock

I am working with Android and I am unsure what exactly UserManager and KeyguardManager do / how they relate with each other.

From the Docs:

UserManager:

```
isUserUnlocked: On devices with direct boot, a user is unlocked only after they've entered their credentials (such as a lock pattern or PIN). On devices without direct boot, a user is unlocked as soon as it starts. When a user is locked, only device-protected data storage is available. When a user is unlocked, both device-protected and credential-protected private app data storage is available.
```

KeyguardManager:

```
isKeyguardLocked: Return whether the keyguard is currently locked.
```

When UserManager is locked, is then also the keyguard locked? Is this also vice-versa? Or do they completely different stuff and are not related at all?

I read the documentation, but especially for the keyguard it is very thin.